# Forwarding Jasmin server SMPP traffic on Linux

Tags: networking, proxy

I'm running the Jasmin SMPP server on Ubuntu Server. The server works locally but now I want to be able to access it over the Internet. I'm not sure how to do this. Should I use a proxy or IP tables or something? The local server is running on `127.0.0.1:2775` and I want it to run on my servers public IP address on the same port. The server is a VPS hosted at DigitalOcean.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What software is it? Some servers need to be configured to accept connections from external hosts, but this depends on the software itself (e.g. for a web server, Apache is not the same as Ngix when it comes to configuring it).

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Buongiorno Andrea! I'm running Jasmin! The service I'm running uses the smpp protocol so I assume I can't do it with Apache or Nginx.

Comment: Yes you are right, those were just examples because I didn't know specific instances of SMPP server. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto isn't there an universal way?

Comment: There is if the OS is blocking a port, not if the port is open but the application applies security measures to decide what to accept. ;) Could you please specify what installation method you used from the several options [listed here](http://jasmin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/)?

Comment: @andrealazzarotto Hi Andrea, thank you for your help and sorry for my late reply. I've used the Ubuntu method using apt!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to ask. What Ubuntu version is it?

Comment: @andrealazzarotto 16.04!